# let f be non-negative show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f d\mu = \sup \sum_i (\inf_{x \in A_i} f(x))\mu(A_i)$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

let f be non-negative function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \infty$ and $\mu$ the lesbesgue measure. Let $A_i$ be all possible partitions of $\mathbb{R}$ which are finite show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f d\mu = \sup \sum_i (\inf_{x \in A_i} f(x))\mu(A_i)$

I am really close i must say, I've already proven that

$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f d\mu = \int_\mathbb{R} \sup f_n(x)$, where f_n(x) are simple functions which are increasing and positive. So with beppo levi:

$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f d\mu = \int_\mathbb{R} \sup f_n(x) d\mu = \sup \int_\mathbb{R} f_n(x) d\mu$ = $\sup \sum_i y_i\mu(A_i)$.

Where i used in the last equation that each simple functions integral can be written as $\sum_i y_i\mu(A_i)$. I don't know wheter that's correct though, because the simple functions must be less or equal than $f(x)$, i chose the $y_i$ to be $\inf_{x \in A_i} f(x)$.

Comment: Please make your question self-contained (e.g.: What are $A_i$ and $y_i$? Is $\mu$ a finite measure?)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

note that $f$ is non-negative. So f can be written as the limit of a sequence simple functions s.t:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)$ and $f_n(x) \leq f(x)$. furthermore we can take $f_n(x)$ such that $0 \leq f_1 \leq f_2 ......$, so $f(x) = sup_{n} f_n(x)$.

now note that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f = \int_{\mathbb{R}} sup f_n = sup \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n$ by beppo levi.

Now one must see that $f_n = \sum_n y_n 1_{(A_n(x))}$ with $y_n = \inf(f(x)_{x\in A_n})$ because we approximate $f(x)$ from below

Comment: I must also prove:

 $\inf \sum_i (\sup_{x \in A_i} f(x))\mu(A_i) = \infty$ if f is strict positive!